# Groovy method to build <String, List<List>> tokens from String array

Tags: java, optimization, groovy

I have a string array:

```
def invoices = [LEDES98BI V2,
LINE|INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|INVOICE_TOTAL,
1|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|22,
2|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|24,
3|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|26,
4|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|28,]
```

I tried to convert it to `HasMap<String, List<List>>` with key as invoice numbers(`INV-Error_Test1`, `INV-Error_Test2`) and the values are each invoice line:

```
[
INV-Error_Test2:[[3,20150301, INV-Error_Test2,26], [4,20150301, INV-Error_Test2,28]], 
INV-Error_Test1:[[1,20150301, INV-Error_Test1,22], [2,20150301, INV-Error_Test1,24]]
]
```

And this is the method which converts the string array into `<String, List<List>>` tokens:

```
def extractInvoiceLineItems(def invoices) {
    Map invLineItems = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList>>();
    def lineItems = []
    for(int i = 2; i<invoices.length; i++){
       def tokens =  invoices[i].split('\\|') as List
       if(tokens.size != 1) {
        lineItems.add(tokens)           
      }
    }

    for (int i=0; i< lineItems.size; i++) {
        invNumber = lineItems.get(i).get(1)
         if(invLineItems.keySet().find{it == invNumber}) {
            templineItem = invLineItems.get(invNumber)
            templineItem.add(lineItems.get(i))
            invLineItems.put(invNumber,templineItem)      
         }
        else {
            def list = []
            list.add(lineItems.get(i))
            invLineItems.put(invNumber,list)
        }      
    }
invLineItems
}
```

I am using lots of traditional for loops and am wondering whether it can be simplified further (using closures or any other way).

UPDATE1:
I am trying to print the invoice details per `INVOICE_NUMBER` as below

```
def lines = invoices*.split('\\|').findAll{ it.size()>1 }
def heads = lines.first()
def invLineItems = lines.tail().collect{ [heads, it].transpose().collectEntries() }.groupBy{ it.INVOICE_NUMBER }
// => [INV-Error_Test1:[[LINE:1, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:22], [LINE:2, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:24]], INV-Error_Test2:[[LINE:3, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:26], [LINE:4, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:28,]]]

println " INV-Error_Test2 Details "
invLineItems.get('INV-Error_Test2').each{ 
    it.each{k,v ->
print "LINE = "+ it['LINE']
print " "+" INVOICE_DATE = "+it['INVOICE_DATE']
print " "+" INVOICE_TOTAL  = "+it['INVOICE_TOTAL']
    }
 }
```

But am seeing all the map values when am trying to print the specific value. can someone help me out?

UPDATE2: Am trying to update the `Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> invoices` with the invoiceErrors as below

```
InvoiceError // is an entity with below attributes
{ String errorMessage,
  String invoiceNumber    
}
ErrorMessage                                          invoiceNumber   
-------------                                       -------------------     
File Error : The file is in an unsupported format   INV-Error_Test1
Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported             INV-Error_Test1
Line : 2 MATH ERROR                                 INV-Error_Test1
Line : 3 MATH ERROR                                 INV-Error_Test2
Line : 3 Invoice does not foot Reported             INV-Error_Test2
```

Am trying to achieve below map 
    If the error message doesnt have a line number it need to be appended at the top level as `invLineItems.put('error',['INV-Error_Test1' :`File Error : The file is in an unsupported format`])`
   Otherwise errormessage should be appended to the  matching INVOICE and linenumber as below

```
invLineItems = [INV-Error_Test1:[[LINE:1, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:22, error : `Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported`], 
                                [LINE:2, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:24, error : `Line : 2 MATH ERROR`],
                INV-Error_Test2:[[LINE:3, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:26, , error : `Line : 3 MATH ERROR | Line : 3 Invoice does not foot Reported`], 
                                [LINE:4, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:28,]],
                error : [[INV-Error_Test1:`File Error : The file is in an unsupported format`]]
```

I wrote the below method to achieve the above

```
def regex = "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+";
for (e in invLineItems ){
  def errors =  lipErrors.findAll{it.invoiceNumber==e.key} // finding the error messages with the invoice number
  errors.each{  // fetching the line numbre from error message and finding the matching record the invoice number and line number in invLineItems 
     int lineNumber
     if (it.errorMessage.matches(regex)) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(it.errorMessage);
            if (m.find()) {
                 lineNumber = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
            }
          println "lineNumber = "+lineNumber
        }

    if(e.value['LINE_ITEM_NUMBER'].find{it==lineNumber.toString()}) {
      def data = lipErrors.findAll{it.invoiceNumber==e.key && it.errorMessage.matches("^Line\\s+"+lineNumber+"?\\:\\s+"+lineNumber+"?.+")}
      e.getValue().each{it.put("error", data.errorMessage.join("|"))}

     }   

  }
}
```

The code doesnt look like Groovy and using traditional java code mostly, am wondering whether the code can be simplified with Groovy approach

Comment: could you please provide your data with the output of `.inspect()` - this invalid "strings" make it practically impossible to write some code to test it.

Comment: see comment on answer about the problem after the update

Comment: I removed ` k,v` and tried `it['LINE']` but getting below error groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: get for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry Possible solutions: key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are after is [`groupBy`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#Maps-Grouping)

This should do:

```
def invoices = [
'LEDES98BI V2',
'LINE|INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|INVOICE_TOTAL',
'1|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|22',
'2|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|24',
'3|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|26',
'4|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|28,']

// get all "valid" lines
def lines = invoices*.split('\\|').findAll{ it.size()>1 }
// remember the keys (headline) for later (optional)
def heads = lines.first()

// as map of maps
println lines.tail().collect{ [heads, it].transpose().collectEntries() }.groupBy{ it.INVOICE_NUMBER }
// => [INV-Error_Test1:[[LINE:1, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:22], [LINE:2, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:24]], INV-Error_Test2:[[LINE:3, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:26], [LINE:4, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:28,]]]

// or just as you had it (map of string list)
println lines.tail().groupBy{ it[2] }
// => [INV-Error_Test1:[[1, 20150301, INV-Error_Test1, 22], [2, 20150301, INV-Error_Test1, 24]], INV-Error_Test2:[[3, 20150301, INV-Error_Test2, 26], [4, 20150301, INV-Error_Test2, 28,]]]
```

**Edit**

Version that prints all the lines for a certain invoice number:

```
def invLineItems = lines.tail().collect{ [heads, it].transpose().collectEntries() }.groupBy{ it.INVOICE_NUMBER }
```

This now is a a `Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>>`.  So getting one element gives you the list.  The `each` iterates the list and `it` there is a map:

```
invLineItems.get('INV-Error_Test2').each{ 
        print "LINE = "+ it['LINE']
        print " "+" INVOICE_DATE = "+it['INVOICE_DATE']
        print " "+" INVOICE_TOTAL  = "+it['INVOICE_TOTAL']
        println ""
}
```

Or quick an dirty:

```
print invLineItems.get('INV-Error_Test2')*.collect{ k, v -> [k,"=",v].join(" ") }*.join(", ").join("\n")
```

Comment: Wow, thats pretty clean and very minimal code. I really appreciate it.  I tried your map of maps as `def invLineDetails = lines.tail().collect{ [heads, it].transpose().collectEntries() }.groupBy{ it.INVOICE_NUMBER }` and tried to get the `LINE` as `println invLineDetails.get('INV-Error_Test1').get(0).get('LINE')` but am getting it as null. how do I access LINE from map of maps?

Comment: then you have a typo somewhere. use my code just as a groovy script and try it there. `['INV-Error_Test1'][0].LINE` works fine for me.  alos using `get()` works fine.

Comment: yeah it was a typo, I was bale to use `['INV-Error_Test1'][0].LINE`

Comment: am having issue whith printing specific value from map of map. Can you check the updated question please

Comment: you are recursing one level to much.  remove the `it.each{ k,v ->`-level there.  by that you print all the it['LINE']... for each element.

Comment: I removed ` k,v` and tried `it['LINE']` but getting below error  `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: get for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
Possible solutions: key`

Comment: Can you please check the UPDATE2 part and suggest any changes?

Comment: Is there a way to make a new hash map of <InvoiceNUmber, InvoiceTotal> without iterating over invLineItems

Comment: Can you also help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570648/java-8-find-and-replace-matching-strings

Comment: Can u help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789467/groovy-groupby-field-with-white-spaces