# Java 8 find and replace matching string(s)

Tags: java, regex, string, java-8

I am trying to find a string from `messages.properties` in an `errorMessage` and if the `errorMessage` has the string I need to replace it with corresponding value

I have `messages.properties` as below

```
inv_date=INVOICE DATE
inv_id=INVOICE NUMBER
cl_id=CLIENT ID
lf_matter_id=LAW FIRM MATTER ID
inv_total_net_due=INVOICE TOTAL
(inv_start_date|invoice start date)=BILLING START DATE
(inv_end_date|invoice end date)=BILLING END DATE
inv_desc=INVOICE DESCRIPTION
units=LINE ITEM NUMBER OF UNITS
discount_amount=LINE ITEM ADJUSTMENT AMOUNT
total_amount=LINE ITEM TOTAL
(charge_date|charge date)= LINE ITEM DATE
acca_task=LINE ITEM TASK CODE
acca_expense=LINE ITEM EXPENSE CODE
acca_activity= LINE ITEM ACTIVITY CODE
(tk_id|time keeper id)=TIMEKEEPER ID
charge_desc=LINE ITEM DESCRIPTION
lf_id=LAW FIRM ID
(BaseRate|Rate|tk_rate)=LINE ITEM UNIT COST
tk_level=TIMEKEEPER CLASSIFICATION
cl_matter_id=CLIENT MATTER ID
```

My `errorMesage` can have any of the (left side)string and I need to replace it with right side string value

Below are couple of sample error messages

```
String errorMesage1 = "Line 3 : Could not parse inv_date value" 
String errorMesage2 = "Line : 1 BaseRate is a required field"
```

below is my method which conversts the error message

```
public static String toUserFriendlyErrorMessage(String message) {
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages");
    for(String key : rb.keySet()){
        String header = rb.getString(key);
        if(message.contains(key)) {
          return message.replaceAll(key, rb.getString(key));           
        }
    }
    return message;

}
```

Below is the expected output:
for errorMessage1 it works fine

```
System.out.println(toUserFriendlyErrorMessage(errorMessage1)); ==> Line 3 : Could not parse INVOICE DATE value
```

But for errorMessage2 its not working. It doesnt replace `BaseRate` with `LINE ITEM UNIT COST`

```
System.out.println(toUserFriendlyErrorMessage(errorMessage2)); ==> Line : 1 BaseRate is a required field
```

Is there a way to find the occurance of multiple strings and replace it with its corresponding value?

For example: Find `(BaseRate|Rate|tk_rate)` and replace the string with `LINE ITEM UNIT COST`

Also am wondering can this method simplified further in java 8?

Comment: Why don't you have an entry for BaseRate (and another one for Rate, and another one for tk_rate) in the properties file. Why do you use ResourceBundle (which is supposed to help with internatioanlization), rather than java.util.Properties? Why do you use replaceAll(), which takes a regex as argument, rather than replace(), which takes a simple String?

Comment: @JBNizet I just want to eliminate the redundancy so I tried grouping BaseRate,Rate,tk_rate together. Also whats the better way to handle this properties file without ResourceBundle?

Comment: As I said: Properties. Eliminating the redundancy doesn't bring a significant advantage, and makes your code much more complex. Make things simple and straightforward.

Comment: Okay, I'll have separate values for BaseRate,Rate,tk_rate. So can it be simplfied further in java 8?

Comment: I think you should reconsider your design and use individual keys for the several "aliases". The problem is that the keys in those properties files are not supposed to contain spaces -- parantheses or not -- so the files are not parsed correctly. If you print the keys, you will see that they are truncated at the first space, e.g. `(inv_start_date|invoice`.

Comment: @tobias_k I understand, I'll switch to `Map<String,String>` instead of file. Can the method simplified further in Java 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should reconsider your design and use individual keys for the several "aliases" - or probably even better: No aliases at all and just one key per replacement. The problem is that the keys in those properties files are not supposed to contain spaces -- parantheses or not -- so the files are not parsed correctly. If you print the keys, you will see that they are truncated at the first space, e.g. `(inv_start_date|invoice start date)` becomes `(inv_start_date|invoice`.

Of course, this also means that, even if you split those "aliases" into separate keys, you can not have keys like `invoice start date`, as it still contains spaces and will not be parsed correctly.

You *could* just put those replacements into a regualr `Map` in your Java source code:

```
static Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
static {
    replacements.put("inv_date", "INVOICE DATE");
    replacements.put("(BaseRate|Rate|tk_rate)", "LINE ITEM UNIT COST");
    // ... more stuff ...
}
```

Or parse the file manually, splitting the strings at `=` and putting them into a `Map`.

And since keys like `(BaseRate|Rate|tk_rate)` are in fact valid regular expressions, you can just use [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to replace them in all their variants. If they are not contained in the string, `replaceAll` will just do nothing, so the `contains` check is not really necessary.

```
public static String toUserFriendlyErrorMessage(String message) {
    for (String key : replacements.keySet()) {
        message = message.replaceAll(key, replacements.get(key));
    }
    return message;
}
```

Example output:

```
Line 3 : Could not parse INVOICE DATE value
Line : 1 LINE ITEM UNIT COST is a required field
```

Or, if you want to use some "Java 8 magic", you could use `reduce`, but personally, I think the loop is more readable.

```
    return replacements.keySet().stream()
            .reduce(message, (s, k) -> s.replaceAll(k, replacements.get(k)))
            .toString();
```