# Groovy GroupBy field with and without white spaces

Tags: collections, groovy

I have invoices list as below

```
def invoices = [
'LEDES98BI V2',
'LINE|INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|INVOICE_TOTAL',
'1|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|22',
'2|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|24',
'3|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|26',
'4|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|28,']
```

I am trying to do groupBy on the above collection with `INVOICE_NUMBER` and trying to achieve map with `INVOICE_NUMBER` and lines as values, below code does it

```
def lines = invoices*.split('\\|').findAll{ it.size()>1 }
def heads = lines.first()
def invoiceMap =  lines.tail().collect{ [heads, it].transpose().collectEntries() }.groupBy{ it.INVOICE_NUMBER }
```

If I print `invoiceMap` I get what I intended as below map

```
 [INV-Error_Test1:[[LINE:1, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:22], 
                   [LINE:2, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:24]], 
  INV-Error_Test2:[[LINE:3, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:26], 
                   [LINE:4, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:28,]]
  ]
```

But but if the `INVOICE_NUMBER` has any white spaces with it in the `invoices` map my code doesnt work. Can someone help me to make my code work with white spaces on `INVOICE_NUMBER`?

Comment: Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing, which doesn't work?  A space in the column title (using `INVOICE NUMBER` instead of `INVOICE_NUMBER`)?  Or a space in the column value (`2015 03 01` instead of `20150301`)?

Comment: A space in the column title (using INVOICE_NUMBER  with some white spaces instead of INVOICE_NUMBER)

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper CSV parser, rather than rolling your own.

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

def invoices = [
'LEDES98BI V2',
'LINE|INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|INVOICE_TOTAL',
'1|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|22',
'2|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|24',
'3|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|26',
'4|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|28,']

def data = parseCsv(invoices.drop(1).join('\n'), separator:'|')
def invoiceMap = data.collect().groupBy { it.INVOICE_NUMBER }
```

Or with a space in the column title:

```
def invoices = [
'LEDES98BI V2',
'LINE|INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE NUMBER|INVOICE_TOTAL',
'1|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|22',
'2|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|24',
'3|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|26',
'4|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|28,']

def data = parseCsv(invoices.drop(1).join('\n'), separator:'|')
def invoiceMap = data.collect().groupBy { it.'INVOICE NUMBER' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to quote your name, like this

```java
def invoiceMap = lines.tail().collect{ [heads, it].transpose().collectEntries() }.groupBy{ it.'INVOICE NUMBER' }
```