# Why isn't split working here?

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm trying to take a filename that's being passed from a tsv and split it into an array, like so:

```
    new File("filenames.tsv").eachLine( { String file_iter ->
        println file_iter
        def details = file_iter.split(".")
        println details 
    })
```

The output of the printlns:

```
stad.all.16jan15.TP.pwpv
[]
```

Why is the array empty? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Consider using a csv parser as well, instead of rolling your own. https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv/blob/master/README.md

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30790145/6509 for example usage configuring the separator

Comment: @tim_yates : What would the advantage of that be, when I can do it easily, in 4 lines of code? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: Because you can't trust text files to be in the exact format you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) takes a regular expression as an argument.
`.` is a regular expression special character, see the [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html):

> Because we want to do more than simply search for literal pieces of text, we need to reserve certain characters for special use. In the regex flavors discussed in this tutorial, there are 12 characters with special meanings: the backslash \, the caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus sign +, the opening parenthesis (, the closing parenthesis ), and the opening square bracket [, the opening curly brace {, These special characters are often called "metacharacters".
>
> If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex, you need to escape them with a backslash. If you want to match 1+1=2, the correct regex is 1+1=2. Otherwise, the plus sign has a special meaning.

With Java string literal syntax the backslash is the escape character, so in Java you have to double-escape the backslash to get it to show up properly. [Groovy adds options for specifying string literals](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-string-strings-strings.html) so you can avoid the double-escape using the slashy string syntax.

As an example in groovysh:

```
groovy:000> s = 'asdf.zxcv.qwerty'
===> asdf.zxcv.qwerty
```

Without an escape the period means everything's a delimiter, so the result is empty

```
groovy:000> s.split('.')
===> []
```

Using the Java double-escape syntax

```
groovy:000> s.split('\\.')
===> [asdf, zxcv, qwerty]
```

Using slashy string literal syntax

```
groovy:000> s.split(/\./)  
===> [asdf, zxcv, qwerty]
```

Be aware that even though the closure is an argument to eachLine, you don't need to enclose the closure in parens, you can write it as:

```
new File('filenames.tsv').eachLine { String file_iter ->
    println file_iter
    def details = file_iter.split(/\./)
    println details 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw an example that didn't use parens in the docs, but the titan code example I was looking at did, so I just went with it.

Comment: @Lauren: it doesn't hurt anything. but omitting them is normal style.